# T-Tree or B-Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree, in-memory-database

T-tree algorithm is described in [this paper](http://www.vldb.org/conf/1986/P294.PDF) 
And T*-Tree is an improvement from T-tree for better use of query operations, including range queries and which contains all other good features of T-tree.
This algorithm is described in this paper "T*-tree: A Main Memory Database Index Structure for Real-Time Applications".
According to this research paper, T-Tree is faster than B-tree/B+tree when datasets fit in the memory.
I implemented T-Tree/T*Tree as they described in these papers and compared the performance with B-tree/B+tree, but B-tree/B+tree perform better than T-Tree/T*Tree in all test cases (insertion, deletion, searching).
I read that T-Tree is an efficient index structure for in-memory database, and it used by Oracle TimesTen. But my results did not show that.
If anyone may know the reason or have any comment about that, it will be great to hear from her (or him).

Comment: Show your results and your test method.

Comment: or maybe this old fashion T-tree is not efficient.depending on Old T-Tree paper , We Can't Be 100 Percent Sure Of T-Tree efficiency. for all who look negatively on my question, I just try my best to implement t-tree as it described in the paper and compare it with b-tree and found this results. I also implement B-tree by myself so I do the same effort for both of t-tree and b-tree

Comment: A study from three decades ago will have used hardware with _very_ different memory hierarchy characteristics, and CPUs (no multi-core back then, let alone inhomogeneous ones) that had a hard time to saturate the memory interface.

Comment: @greybeard, thank you for this answer.

Comment: Oracle Timesten now uses B-Trees by default, in case you're still wondering about that.

Answer (score 6):

T-Trees are not a fundamental data structure in the same sense that AVL trees or B-trees are. They are just a hacked version of balanced binary trees and as such there may or may not be niche applications where they offer decent performance.

In this day and age they are bound to suffer horribly because of their poor locality, both in the sense of expected block/page transfer counts and in the sense of cache locality. The latter is evident since in all node accesses of a search except for the very last one, only the boundary values will be checked against the search key - all the rest is paged in or cached for nought.

Compare this to the excellent access locality of B-trees in general and B+trees in particular (not to mention cache-oblivious and cache-conscious versions that were designed explicitly with memory performance charactistics in mind).

Similar problems exist with the rebalancing. In the B-tree world many variations - starting with B+ and Blink - have been developed and perfected in order to achieve desired amortised performance characteristics, including aspects like concurrency (locking/latching) or the absence thereof. So most of the time you can simply go out and find a B-tree variation that fits your performance profile - or use the simple classic B+tree and be certain of decent results.

T-trees are more complicated than comparable B-trees and it seems that they have nothing to offer in the way of performance *in general*, given that the times of commodity hardware with a single-level memory 'hierarchy' have been gone for decades. Not only is the hard disk the new memory, the converse is also true and main memory is the new hard disk now. I.e. even without NUMA the cost of bringing data from main memory into the cache hierarchy is so high that it pays to minimise page transfers - which is precisely what B-trees and their variations do and the T-tree doesn't. Closer to the processor core it's the number of cache line accesses/transfers that matters but the picture remains the same.

In fact, if you take the idea of binary search - which is provably optimal - and think about ways of arranging the search keys in a manner that plays well with memory hierarchies (caches) then you invariably end up with something that looks uncannily like a B-tree...

If you program for performance then you'll find that winners are almost always located somewhere in the triangle between sorted arrays, B-trees and hashing. Even balanced binary trees are only competitive if their comparatively poor performance takes the back seat in the face of other considerations and key counts are fairly small, i.e. not more than a couple million.

Comment: (Well, even the venerable DEC VAX-11/750 mentioned in the original article had a whopping 4 KBytes of cache, main memory starting at 1MB (and not (originally) going multi-digit).)