# B-Tree vs T-Tree - For lower workloads which is better?

Tags: database, performance, indexing, database-design, database-performance

Our application is using database(in-memory) which was using T-Tree until very recently.
Now, we have migrated to B-Tree and we have observed that for higher workloads(with millions of records residing in db) the performance significantly improves. The account information is already created(insertion - 4M) and then upon processing they are updated.

However, for another product variant which does operates very low number of records saw the decrease in the throughput. Here, the account information was temporarily created(insert), processed(few updates) and then cleaned up(deletion). At any given we do not aim to process more then 100 account profiles per second.
In this case, we observed that there is significant performance difference with T-Tree and B-Tree.

B-Tree seems to perform worse for the latter case.

I could not find much information on internet for specific cases in which B-Tree might perform not as good as T-Tree.

Answer (score 1):

T Trees perform better on data sets that are in memory, while B Trees perform better on data sets that are on disk.

This serves to reason that T Trees work better on smaller data sets, since they'll likely fit into memory in their entirety (and stay there for a while)

**Edit**

Found this:
[T-Tree or B-Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150637/t-tree-or-b-tree)

> In this day and age [T Trees] are bound to suffer horribly because of their poor locality, both in the sense of expected block/page transfer counts and in the sense of cache locality.